# How to rewrite registerFunction for DB2, in Hibernate 6.3.1.?

Tags: java, hibernate, gradle, db2, cxf

Here is my artifacts of Hibernate. I've upgraded them from 5.6.15 to 6.3.1

```
implementation (group: 'org.hibernate.orm', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '6.3.1.Final')
implementation (group: 'org.hibernate.orm', name: 'hibernate-c3p0', version: '6.3.1.Final')
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.6.15.Final'
implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:8.0.1.Final'
```

Also here is my impacted code which I used to extends DB2Dialect earlier

```
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;

public class DB2Dialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect {

    public DB2Dialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("myFunction", new StandardSQLFunction("myFunction"));
    }
}
```

I'm getting below error after upgrade

```
The method registerFunction(String, StandardSQLFunction) is undefined for the type DB2Dialect
```

So any Idea or reference about how to rewrite this code.?
-Thanks